# Attributes panel are changed later updating page-primefaces

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am working with css of the primefaces in a panel, I want to show to the panel without border and padding = 0, so I have the following snippet and it works when I run the aplication

```
.ui-panel .ui-panel-content {
border: 0 none;
padding: 0;
```

}

However when I update the page,  the border is painted and padding doesn't have the value 0, why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `padding: 0;` will probably be overridden with every update by JavaScript, to avoid it you'll need to use:

---

**CSS**

```
padding = 0 !important;
```

---

`!important` makes a style that is applied to ignore any subsequent rules, especially those nasty inline ones. Don't overuse it!